# MS Access - Editing fields after making them autopopulate only edits 1st record (forms)

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access, combobox

Just a headsup, I am quite new to relational databases so my question could be a simple fix.

Currently, I have a table with the following data.

ID(1 ,2,3,4,5)

Location(Canada, USA, Japan, Australia, Venezuela)

Count(4,6,2,91,23)

I created a form with a combobox and two text fields. The goal is that I want to be able to click the combobox, have it show all the ID's and when I click an ID, it autopopulates the other two text fields with the corresponding information. After googling a bit, I found a way to do is. Within the Event tab under "on Change" for the combobox, I wrote the these two lines of code.

Me.txtLocation = Me.cboID.Column(1)

Me.txtCount = Me.cboID.Column(2)

However, I also want to be able to edit this information once it has been autopopulated. The problem I'm having is that when I change any of the two textfields, it always edits the first records.

So for example, if I click ID #4, and I change the "Count", it will change the "Count" for the ID #1. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. (I have programming experience but not with VBA)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Private Sub txtCount_AfterUpdate()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE aDuh SET Count = '" & Me.Count & "', Location = '" & Me.txtLocation & "' WHERE ID = " & Me.cboID & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

End Sub

Private Sub txtLocation_AfterUpdate()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "UPDATE aDuh SET Location = '" & Me.txtLocation & "', Count = '" & Me.txtCount & "' WHERE ID = " & Me.cboID & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind your form to a table.  Put a textbox on your form with it's Visible property set to False.  In that textbox, put the value of your Primary Key field (which should be an AutoNumber field)  Then when you update your record, pass an UPDATE SQL statement where you update your table based on the value of your Primary Key

Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "UPDATE aDuh SET Location = '" & Me.txtLocation & "', Count = '" & Me.txtCount & "' WHERE ID = " & Me.cboID & ""

DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

Comment: How do I do the Update SQL statement part? I'm extremely inexperienced with SQL and all I know is how to do is select columns in queries.

Comment: @santaaimonce - See my edit above.  You'll have to make obvious changes to the code to fit your specific field and table names.

Comment: syntax (missing operator) between Me.txtMyField & ", MyField2= '" ?

Comment: **You'll have to make obvious changes to the code to fit your specific field and table names.**

Comment: also, if I don't bind it to a table, everything just stops working (the two lines of code I wrote before) I did make changes. Heres what I have. Dim strSQL As String strSQL = "UPDATE testTable SET Location = '" & Me.txtLocation & ", Count = '" & Me.txtCount & " WHERE ID = " & Me.cboID & "" DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)

Comment: I did notice I forgot to put a single quote after the double quote following both control names, but you still need to make the appropriate changes to the sample code I posted.

Comment: I just edited my sample code above.  If your ID field is numeric, you should be able to use the code as-is.  If it's text, you'll need to wrap it in single quotes like the other 2 are.

Comment: Johnny, hopefully you can see this but after further testing, I found out only one of them works. The update statement works for the Location field, but when I try to update the Count field, it always starts from the first entry, and everytime I try to change any of the records, it updates the next one. For example, I want to edit the count field for the first record, it edits the 1st record. If i want to edit the 1st record again, it edits the 2nd record. If i want to edit the 1st record again, it edits the 3rd record. Once it goes past the last entry, it creates a new record. :\

Comment: I edited the original post to show what code I have down right now.

Comment: Check the value of strSQL in your subs.  You can either put a code break point in, or a messagebox.  See if you can figure out what values it thinks me.txtLocation, me.txtCount and me.cboID are, and whether those values make sense at that specific time.

Comment: Everything seems right. When I enter in a new number (lets say 14) to the 2nd record in the count field, this is what I get.

strSQL = "Update aDuh Set Location = 'USA', Count = '14' Where ID = 2" but for some reason for the count it still edits the next consecutive record

Comment: And ID is an AutoNumber field set as a Primary Key with no duplicates?  That just doesn't make sense.  It's updating the record where ID = 3, even though the SQL statement clearly says "WHERE ID=2"??  I'm at a loss on that, there's no logical reason why that would happen.

Comment: Yes ID is an AutoNumber field, is the primary key and has no duplicates. Would I be putting down the same thing for the after update for both the Location and Count? Or would they have different lines of code? Also, the Count is an integer compared to the Location which is text. Would that have an effect on it?

Comment: Hmmm...  Somehow, somewhere, the ID is changing to the next value and then re-running this again.  I know this isn't exactly what you want, but you might want to try putting one button on the form called "Update", and the user clicks that button to update the record.  I think that would be a safer way to do it anyway.  So, take the AfterUpdate subs out, add one button to your form and copy/paste the code to the OnClick event of the button.

Comment: That works! I'm pretty sure my boss is going to fine with this change. Thank you so much!